# Why is an archaic word for gambler, これしゃ, just これ(をする)人

Tags: etymology

Is there any context for why これ referred to gambling, like an euphemism, any history? I have no idea about the history of gambling in Japan.

Comment: Off topic, but I should ask if 達 comes from 立ち as in 成り立ち

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/) tries to include etymologies when there are theories about them.About [達]{たち}, see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/達#Japanese), which says that [達]{たち} may be borrowing from Old Korean \*/tatVk/ or Middle Chinese \*dat (semantically Korean source would be better match).

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask additional questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refrain from asking questions based on the false assumption that Japanese people know every rare historical word in a large dictionary. これしゃ seems to be listed in some large dictionaries, but it is a word recognized by almost no one. It's also virtually nonexistent in creative works published in the last 200 years or so; I checked with 青空文庫全文検索, なろう全文検索 and BCCWJ, and although there are few instances of 是者, none of them seemed to be related to gambling. How did you come across this word?

In any case, judging from [this entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%AD%A4%E8%80%85%E3%83%BB%E6%98%AF%E8%80%85-2040735), it seems to mean nothing more than "this (type of) person". It was probably originally used with certain gestures. In some community at some point in time, "this type of person" might have had a specific meaning as argot, but it is now completely forgotten.

However, expressions like そっち系の人 are sometimes used today to indirectly refer to gang members, people from certain political/religious groups, or people with unique hobbies. What it specifically refers to depends entirely on the context and, if any, a gesture associated with it.

Comment: Also, is the extremely obscure word 虚空無天 a kanbun word?

Comment: @StarPeep Can I ask, how did you come up with a rare word like これしゃ? It seems to me that there is no realistic chance of encountering this word unless you've randomly pulled it from a dictionary. I may have seen 虚空無天 somewhere before, but why do you want to know the history of a word that 99% of native speakers would never use in their lifetime? There's nothing I can do other than trying a Google search on your behalf.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thanks so much! I came across the word on jisho (Which explains a lot, I don't know a better dictionary though because jisho has an advanced search) while looking for terms with 此. (As in こそあど)

Comment: @StarPeep It can be helpful to look at things like the definition tags for the word (this word is marked as "Archaic"). You can also click on the "Links" below the word and get example sentences, and if (as in this case) there are zero example sentences you may be looking at a dead word.